# File search in Windows with "ß" or "ss" in filename

Tags: windows, search

How can I find files under Windows which have a similar filename?
In the German language, there are words which can be written with "ß" as well as with "ss". According to a forum post, this can be a problem that the Windows backup tool does not start. To investigate the suggestion, I would like to run a file search that gives me all files that are named with **ß** or **ss**.
Example:

```
\Documents\Der Einfluss von Goethe in Götz von Berlichingen.docx
\Documents\Der Einfluß von Goethe in Götz von Berlichingen.docx
```

Is it possible to create such a search function with the file explorer or via the console?

Answer (score 0):

[This Superuser URL](http://superuser.com/questions/1161581) explains how to use regular expressions in Powershell, which can be used for finding files.

I don't find more information about this, but generally the `OR`-operator is the pipe character ("`|`"), so for you it might come down to something like:

```
PowerShell Prompt> dir | ?{$_.name -match "^*[ss|ß]*.txt$"}
```

(This does not work entirely, but it gives an idea in which direction to search.)